# Edit page button is now missing in SPOL

Tags: sharepoint-online, edit

Today I noticed the Edit page button is missing everywhere on classic pages, on all sites, except for home and wiki pages. Previously was available on all list, libraries, and their related pages.

We have classic sites that use this function to add web parts to new/edit/properties pages in lists and libraries. Although this is not the path forward with modern, am surprised if this functionality has been axed. We need at least to be able to maintain existing legacy sites.

Permissions are good, am site owner with full control in all areas of all tenants.

Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites is enabled in admin settings.

Since all tenants are affected am assuming this is Microsoft's continued effort to kill off classic sites. If so, is there any way around this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just checked some classic pages in a couple of my tenants and I can still edit them using the **Edit Page** button in the ribbon or the **Edit page** option from the gear menu. Are these options no longer available to you?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, you can edit **Wiki pages** and **Web Part pages** using the **Edit Page** button in the ribbon or the **Edit Page** option in the gear menu.

Site pages do not support classic mode, so the Edit Page button in the ribbon cannot be used.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]